# How to stop playsoundfilenamed?

Tags: ios

Im using this code to add background music to my game levels

```
[self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"dasdas.mp3" waitForCompletion:NO]];
```

I want it to stop when Game Over happens. Is there a way to cancel/stop the `SKAction`, lower volume, anything to stop it?

Thanks

Comment: it's about sound files and skaction.
this thread has the answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/22590464/1242291

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
[node runAction:action]
```

use:

```
[node runAction:action withKey:@"BackgroundMusicAction"]
```

Then stop it by calling the `SKNode`'s method:

```
- (void)removeActionForKey:(NSString *)key;
```

with a key you used for creating the action.

Comment: Im still confused, Im a NOOB. What do I write for node, and NSSTRig and key, can you explain me, it will be a great deal

Answer (score 0):

instead of [node runAction withKey:@"BackgroundMusicAction"];

You would want to use [self runAction withKey:@"BackgroundMusicAction"];

rmaddy's code is right, its just in a generic form.