# How to stop/cancel PlaySoundFileNamed?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skaction

Im using this code to add background music to my game levels

```
[self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"dasdas.mp3" waitForCompletion:NO]];
```

I want it to stop when Game Over happens. Is there a way to cancel/stop the SKAction, lower volume, anything to stop it?

I know Im suppose to use this code

Instead of:

```
[node runAction:action withKey:@"BackgroundMusicAction"]
```

Then stop it by calling the SKNode's method:

```
- (void)removeActionForKey:(NSString *)key;
```

with a key you used for creating the action.

but how do I create a key for the first code, playsoundfilenamed and what do I type on the NSString or how do I connect them, Im a NOOB, help please

Comment: you can't stop a sound started from an SKAction - answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22562493/how-to-stop-a-audio-skaction

Answer (score 1):

You have the answer in the question itself.

First, you need to assign a key

```
[self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"dasdas.mp3"
                           waitForCompletion:NO] 
        withKey: @"BackgroundMusicAction"];
```

Now, you are running an action with the key *BackgroundMusicAction*

In order to stop this action, you will call

```
[self removeActionForKey:@"BackgroundMusicAction"];
```

Comment: the music still plays, is it because im calling the stop action under my -(void)game over?

Answer (score 0):

You can choose whatever you put as the *key*, as long as you use the same for run and remove:

```
SKAction *action = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"dasdas.mp3"
                              waitForCompletion:NO];
[node runAction:action
        withKey:@"MyGameBackgroundMusicAction"];
```

Later :

```
[node removeActionForKey:@"MyGameBackgroundMusicAction"];
```

Comment: I get this message "use of undeclared identifier node"

Comment: In the code above, you call methods on a *node* object. The code you put in your question suggests you might want to use *self* instead here. Note that you must call *runAction* and *removeAction* on the same object.