# How to stop a sound action in swift spriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

i am a swift beginner trying to build a game with a sound in it. i use swift SpriteKit and also AVFoundation as my sound starter. Below is the action i call 
whenever i want a sound action in the game. The sound (background music) plays 
alright but just wouldn't stop when the game is over.

```
self.runAction(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Sound/Gameplay.wav", waitForCompletion: false))
```

Can somebody please help me get this issue behind me? thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at this ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/22590464/4078517

Comment: yes i just did thanks , it was worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You could pause and resume the music?

```
var gameMusic = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Gameplay", ofType: "wav")!), error: nil)

//call playBackgroundMusic func
playBackgroundMusic()

func playBackgroundMusic(){
    gameMusic.play()
}

func pauseBackgroundMusic(){
    gameMusic.pause()
}

if(gameOver){
    pauseBackgroundMusic()
}
```